# How to OR & AND both operators in the same SQL on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a search SQL I need `OR` & `AND` both in the same SQL.

Below my code for one:

```
Post.where('category IN (?) OR location IN (?) ', params[:category ], params[:location])
```

for two:

```
Post.where('category IN (?) AND location IN (?) ', params[:category ], params[:location])
```

I need not only `OR` also `AND` because my search SQL maybe that could be one or two at a time.

My search box is two parts one time anyone search for only `location` or only `category` & anyone search with two parts `location` & `category` if I take `OR` then not search for two & I take `AND` then not search only one

I'm really appreciated if anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get any error?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Your queries are fine.

Comment: No, any error, my search box is two parts one time anyone search for only location  or only category & anyone search with two parts `location` & `category` if I take `OR` then not search for two & I take `AND` then not search only one @31piy @Fallenhero @llya

Comment: sounds to me more like you need where chaining

Comment: @Fallenhero: yeah, that's a better idea than what I had. :)

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer :P

Comment: This site is dificult for new person

Comment: How are we suppose to know you are a beginner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
@posts = Post.where('true')
@posts = @posts.where(:category => params[:category]) unless params[:category].blank?
@posts = @posts.where(:location => params[:location]) unless params[:location].blank?
```

Rails has this feature where you can chain your `where`s etc. The `where`s will be joined with `AND`. So this code will return all posts, or if a category is given **all posts that match that category** or if a location is given **all posts that match that location** or if both category and location is given **all post that match that category AND that location**

Comment: You're welcome. If you are not looking for exact matches you could do `.where('category LIKE ?', "%#{params[:category]}%")`